# How to style Konsole's QTabBar border?

Tags: kde, css, qt, konsole

I'm having this ugly border in my Konsole v16.04 tab bar:
[image]

My profile css:

```
QTabBar::tab {
    background: #002b36;
    color: #839496;
}
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background: #073642
}
QTabBar {
    background: #002b36;
    border: none;  
}
```

The `border` settings seems to do nothing here :(

Here are some docs for qt's QTabBar: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#qtabbar-widget
And regarding Konsole style sheets for tab bar: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/tabbarstylsheet.html

Anyone has an idea why Konsole is not respecting this setting?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `border-width: 0` ([see here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#border-width-prop)), and perhaps `border-radius: 0` ([here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#border-radius-prop)). I'm not exactly sure where to set these, the docs suggest in a `QLineEdit{...` section.

---

As a side note I haven't actually been able to confirm that either of these do work, as my Konsole refuses to find any `.css` profile I make. In trying to fix that problem I came across the bits above which will hopefully help you.

Comment: Great idea, however it didn't work for me. I've tried applying `border-radius: 0` and `border-width: 0` as well as tacking on `!important` flag but nothing worked :(. Regarding your styling issue: you can specify any css file as your profile simply via `settings->configure konsole->tabbar->user defined stylesheet`; I keep mine at `/.config/konsole.css`

Comment: Something like "border-top:    1px solid orchid;" works for me. There is an awkward bug though - if you already have some other custom-set icon, when a border shows up, that icon is pushed onto the left.

Answer (score 1):

indeed the `border` attribute has no effect. you must, rather intuitively, set the `color` of `QTabBar` to the same as the `background` of `QTaBar::tab`. perhaps it is a bug. hopefully you have found this solution prior to this answer. with this fix, the style sheet in the question will look as follows:

```
QTabBar::tab {
    background: #002b36;
    color: #839496;
}
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background: #073642
}
QTabBar {
    background: #002b36;
    color: #002b36;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Konsole 22.12.3 (Qt 5.15.8), I was able to remove any borders by removing them from `QTabWidget` (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar)):

```
QTabWidget::pane {
    border: none;
}
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic, but maybe still helpful for some coming here: in a PyQt5 based app (Qt 5.15.2) using Fusion and custom dark mode I first tried about everything possible in a stylesheet to get rid of such a white border line at the bottom of an independant (i.e. not inside a QTabWidget) QTabBar, just like shown in the screenshot above, without success, there seemed nothing I can do in a stylesheet to change its color or remove it.
But finally I realized that I only had to call tabBar.setDrawBase(False) to get rid of it. When creating a QTabBar programmatically, drawBase seems to default to True, and that was the problem in my case.

But I guess you can't change this property in Konsole without recompiling it, which is why my answer is propably off-topic.